# Accidentally deleted /var/log/syslog

Tags: 14.04, log, logging, syslog, rsyslog

I accidentally deleted /var/log/syslog and now I can't get rsyslog working.

I was googling, I tried everything I found. To be precise:

I created syslog with touch.

Then I set chmod and chown correctly. Now `ls -al` gives this result:

```
-rw-r-----  1 syslog            adm           0 jún   23 02:36 syslog
-rw-r-----  1 syslog            adm     1557257 jún   23 01:33 syslog.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog            adm      156618 jún   22 07:51 syslog.2.gz
-rw-r-----  1 syslog            adm      155851 jún   21 07:45 syslog.3.gz
-rw-r-----  1 syslog            adm      155199 jún   20 07:35 syslog.4.gz
-rw-r-----  1 syslog            adm      159709 jún   19 07:37 syslog.5.gz
-rw-r-----  1 syslog            adm      156035 jún   18 07:52 syslog.6.gz
-rw-r-----  1 syslog            adm      158478 jún   17 07:55 syslog.7.gz
```

Then I restarted rsyslog service:

```
service rsyslog restart
```

I rebooted the system several times.

I even re-installed rsyslog with `apt-get purge` and `apt-get install`

But none of these helped me. As you can see above, syslog still has a length of 0 bytes, nothing gets logged.

**Edit:**

Even when I'm trying to log something manually, nothing gets logged:

```
# ls -al /var/log/syslog
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 0 jún   23 14:04 /var/log/syslog
# logger "this message should end up in syslog"
# ls -al /var/log/syslog
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 0 jún   23 14:04 /var/log/syslog
```

Permissions of `/var` and `/var/log`:

```
# ls -al /var
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root     4096 dec   16  2015 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root     4096 máj   31 14:14 ..
...
drw-rw---- 22 root syslog   4096 jún   23 14:05 log
```

I'm on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Try `logger "this message should end up in syslog"`. Then see if that gets logged.

Comment: @Jos Now I tried it, nothing

Comment: Is `rsyslog` running? What does `sudo service rsyslog status` say?

Comment: @Jos `rsyslog start/running, process 513`

Comment: did you perhaps change permissions of either /var or /var/log/? is /var on a partition and full? start rsyslog manually under strace and see if it complains

Comment: @Jos Please see my update. I don't remember changing them but it could be a problem. Since on my local 16.04 machine `/var/log`  has `drwxrwxr-x` permissions

Comment: Permissions of `/var/log` on my system are `drwxrwxr-x`.

Comment: jups. must be it: /var/log drwxrwxr-x the drw-rw---- is not good.

Comment: @Jos you make an answer? >:-D

Comment: Thank you guys, `chmod 775 /var/log/` and a reboot helped!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @Rinzwind pointed out: the permissions on the `/var/log` directory may have accidentally been changed. In a fresh install they are `drwxrwxr-x`.

Change your permissions:

`# chmod 775 /var/log`

and `# systemctl restart rsyslog` (or reboot). Test the syslog facility with:

`$ logger "this message should end up in syslog"`

Comment: how to "restart" rsyslog?  perhaps you mean `systemctl restart rsyslog`? please be more spacafic

Comment: Yes, that would be `sudo systemctl restart rsyslog`, or (on older systems) `sudo service rsyslog restart`.

Answer (score 9):

Same problem with server Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
I deleted `/var/log/syslog`.

**Problem is the OWNER / Group of the syslog file !**

Solution :

1. create an empty syslog file
2. With Ubuntu 16.04, the owner group must be **syslog:adm**
3. restart
4. test with logger

Commands:

```
cd /var/log
touch syslog
chown syslog:adm syslog
service rsyslog restart
logger "Didier MISSON logger test"
```

You must see the message in the syslog:

```
less syslog
```